# Learn AngularJS coursera Assignment 3

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

For this part of the assignment, I need to show a list of leaders with jpegs, descriptions, yada yada yada. What I'm getting is an empty row; nothing indicating that there is anything in that row.

What I have done...

I included a factory that returns the list of leaders...

services.js

```
.factory('corporateFactory', function() {
var corpfac = {};

        var leadership = [
            {
                name: "Peter Pan",
                image: 'images/alberto.png',
                designation: "Chief Epicurious Officer",
                abbr: "CEO",
                description: "Our CEO, Peter, credits his hardworking East Asian immigrant parents who undertook the arduous journey to the shores of America with the intention of giving their children the best future. His mother's wizardy in the kitchen whipping up the tastiest dishes with whatever is available inexpensively at the supermarket, was his first inspiration to create the fusion cuisines for which The Frying Pan became well known. He brings his zeal for fusion cuisines to this restaurant, pioneering cross-cultural culinary connections."
            },
            {
                name: "Dhanasekaran Witherspoon",
                image: 'images/alberto.png',
                designation: "Chief Food Officer",
                abbr: "CFO",
                description: "Our CFO, Danny, as he is affectionately referred to by his colleagues, comes from a long established family tradition in farming and produce. His experiences growing up on a farm in the Australian outback gave him great appreciation for varieties of food sources. As he puts it in his own words, Everything that runs, wins, and everything that stays, pays!"
            },
            {
                name: "Agumbe Tang",
                      image: 'images/alberto.png',
                designation: "Chief Taste Officer",
                abbr: "CTO",
                description: "Blessed with the most discerning gustatory sense, Agumbe, our CFO, personally ensures that every dish that we serve meets his exacting tastes. Our chefs dread the tongue lashing that ensues if their dish does not meet his exacting standards. He lives by his motto, You click only if you survive my lick."
            },
            {
                name: "Alberto Somayya",
                image: 'images/alberto.png',
                designation: "Executive Chef",
                abbr: "EC",
                description: "Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. He says, Put together the cuisines from the two craziest cultures, and you get a winning hit! Amma Mia!"
            }

        ];

        // Implement two functions, one named getLeaders,
        // the other named getLeader(index)
        // Remember this is a factory not a service
        corpfac.getLeaders = function(){
            return leadership;
        };

        corpfac.getLeader = function(index){
            return leadership[index];
        };

        return corpfac;

})
```

I have then created a controller that brings in the leaders from the services.js into controllers.js.

controllers.js

```
angular.module('confusionApp')...
    .controller('AboutController', ['$scope', 'corporateFactory', function($scope, corporateFactory){
        $scope.leaders= corporateFactory.getLeaders();
    }])
```

I have then put within the aboutus.html. A way to loop through the leaders one at a time.

aboutus.html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AboutController">
...
<div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <h2>Corporate Leadership</h2>
            <ul class="media-list">
                <li class="media" ng-repeat="leader in leaders">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a ui-sref="app.aboutus">
                            <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{leader.image}} alt={{leader.abbr}}>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{leader.name}} 
                           <small>{{leader.designation}}</small></h2>
                           <p>{{leader.description}}</p>
                       </div>
                   </li>
               </ul>

           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I load up the page, it comes up blank. I have checked the answer on 2 different githubs to confirm what I had done was right and they both had the same exact answer as I did.

Is there something I'm not getting? I'm not getting any errors within the Javascript console so I can't tell if there if there is something wrong there.

Lastly, I know this would be asking a lot, but I need to ask questions on this site, so if you wouldn't mind upvoting, I'd greatly appreciate it. I have had a 0 and 1 on my past questions and they are threatening to cut me off from asking any more questions. Well enough of that sad and desperate plug. I look forward to any and all answers.  Thank you kindly for any help.

**RE-EDIT:** I've included the whole factory this time around as there were some questions regarding it. Also, to clarify the rest of the about us page prints just fine. Just the section with the Corporate Leadership is blank. It actually says "Corporate Leadership" and then has a big ol' blank space before the rest of the page is rendered. I'm trying to create a plunker as we speak to recreate this.

Comment: Could you able to create [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/)? Otherwise, there is not enough information in your question to pin point the issue.

Comment: Try accepting answers on your previous questions if you want an uptick in points

Comment: Where is `leadership` defined? Does controller fire? Are you saying you see nothing on page? Is any routing involved? Create a plunker demo that reproduces problem

Comment: I'm trying to do a plunker, but I'm finding it difficult to run the index.html script as all of the javascript files: angular, angular-ui-router, font-awesome, bootstrap, etc. isn't loading quite properly.

Comment: @charlietfl: leadership is defined before hand. I will re-edit the question to include it. I am not seeing nothing on the page, just nothing within that section of the web page. Also, I tried to uptick your answer from my first question, but it hasn't gone up and this is the third time I'm doing it in three days. Le sigh.

Comment: try accepting answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine in your code, [check this small fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suman_jsfiddle/czuyxjoz/) which has your code snippet :

```
angular.module('confusionApp',[])
.controller('AboutController', ['$scope', 'corporateFactory', function($scope, corporateFactory){
        $scope.leaders= corporateFactory.getLeaders();
    }])
```

Only `[]` were added at the end of `angular.module('confusionApp')` and things were fine.

Let me know if issue is something else.

Comment: Adding the [] for some reason caused the page not to load at all, but once I removed it, everything started to work as planned. Weird.

Comment: If it has helped, accept d answer n vote up please :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a suggestion by BeingSuman and then reverting it back (the solution provided caused the page not to load at all), the page loaded exactly as expected. Very strange, I know. But it worked. Thank you so much to all who have come on board to help.